# Is there a function to transform dataframe columns as inputs to create a dictionary for text mining in R?

Tags: r, text-mining

So I have a data frame with "n" columns. Each column represents a list of keywords which I want to use  to identify specific text. The usual method is the following and here, I set n=3:

```
dict = dictionary(list(V1 = c("x", "y","z"),
                       V2= c("a", "b","c"),V3= c("m", "n","o"))
```

The problem is, if I have many and longer lists of keywords, the works is then more tedious. Therefore, I thought it was possible to use the following method (with the assumption that my dataframe is named "df"):

```
dict = dictionary(list(df$V1,df$V2,df$V3)
```

Understandably, it is not working therefore, my question is how can I make the transformation without having to manually insert the lists of keywords when creating the dictionary ?

Comment: Which package is `dictionary` function from? What are the contents of `df` ? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Ronak. I went back to my code and tried it again. It now works and I posted my answer. Granted, I have a dataframe for a project that is nothing like the one I used here, but I feel confident it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I tried it again and it is working now. I should have attached a reproducible example. Here is the code I used:

```
library("quanteda")
```

The manual way of creating the dictionary

```
dict = dictionary(list(animal = c("cat","mouse", "dog"), 
                   places = c("paris", "milan", "miami"),
                    food = c("lasagnas", "tacos", "burgers")))
```

Creating the dataframe

```
V1 = c("cat","mouse", "dog")
V2 = c("paris", "milan", "miami")
V3 = c("lasagnas", "tacos", "burgers")
df=cbind.data.frame(V1,V2,V3)
```

The initially failed code to facilitate the creation of the dictionary for longer lists, which now works:

```
dict2 = dictionary(list(animal = df$V1, 
                   places =df$V2,
                   food = df$V3))
```

I am using a longer data frame, but I am now confident it is going to work.

Thanks!